# only set variable in psql-script if not specified on the command-line

Tags: postgresql, psql

I want to give the *option* to specify some variables on the command-line for my psql-scripts with.

```
 psql -v myVar=myValue
```

However I found no way to give those variables default values within the sql-script itself. The syntax:

```
\set MyVar defaultValue
```

overwrites the value `myValue` specified on the psql command-line unconditionally.

Is there any way to check if a variable is set within psql?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Setting default values for variables is not supported in psql, but you can do it using a workaround.

This psql command:

```
\set myVar :myVar
```

does nothing if the variable was already set via psql (this means, myVar is set again to his value), otherwise the variable is set literally to the string `:myVar`.

Using this circumstance and the other psql command `\gset`, you can actually set a default value for myVar. Put this on the top of you sql script:

```
\set myVar :myVar
-- now myVar is set to the string ':myVar' if was not already set.
-- Checking it using a CASE statement:
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN :'myVar'= ':myVar'
  THEN 'default_value' 
  ELSE :'myVar' 
END AS "myVar"  \gset -- < \gset call at end of the query
```

It seems to work only with text variables, but you can cast to numeric if you need numeric variables:

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN :'myVar'= ':myVar'
  THEN '10' 
  ELSE :'myVar' 
END::numeric AS "myVar"  \gset
```

#### How does \gset work:

`\gset` allows you to set a variable from the result of a select query. The result variable is named like the column name, this is why you need the clause `AS "myVar"` at the end of the query (don't forget the double quotes if you want to use variables names with uppercase letters).

For example the command:

```
SELECT 'hello' AS var1 \gset
```

sets the variable `var1` to `hello`, the same as

```
\set var1 hello
```

See here for more infos: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Finding this made me glad indeed, especially as it seems to be PostgreSQL folklore more than anything. I'd upvote twice if it were possible.

Answer (score 9):

As of psql version 11, you can do this

```
\if :{?myVar}
\else
   \set myVar default_value
\endif
\echo myVar is :'myVar'
```

See the "Meta-Commands" [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html).

Answer (score 2):

The answer from [Tom-db](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4313133/tom-db) is great but doesn't work when used with /prompt

To use this in the scenario where a user presses enter without adding anything in response to the /prompt don't use the `\set myVar :myVar` part and just use:

```
\prompt "Please provide value " myVar
/*user hits enter */

SELECT CASE
  WHEN :'myVar'= ''
  THEN 'default_value'
  ELSE :'myVar'
END AS "myVar"  \gset

select :'myVar';
```