# Pass parameters to postgres sql script and provide default values if they are not provided

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, sql-scripts

I have a postgres sql script that has a create table statement. Before that it tries to connect to database using `\c dbname` inside same script. I want to pass this dbname as parameter to this sql script. If no parameter is passed it needs to assign a default value declared inside the script.

I see parameters can be passed to postgres sql script like eg:  `psql -v dbname = testdb -h localhost -U postgres -a -f create_table.sql`

and variables can be declared inside postgres sql file using eg: `dbname VARCHAR := "local_db";` but having trouble how to check if parameter is passed or not and assign default value if it is not passed.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at this one, it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582600/only-set-variable-in-psql-script-if-not-specified-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a variable to `psql` with

```
psql -v 'var=value'
```

In the script you can reference the variable as `:var`. There are also `:'var'` and `:"var"` to get quoted versions of the value.